# Windows 7 Memory, Disk Space, and CPU Usage?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, performance

How is Windows 7 compared to Vista when it comes to the amount of memory (both idle and during game play for example) it uses, the amount of disk space each take up, and CPU usage?

I would like the answer to come from actual usage of the systems, not what Microsoft says.

Comment: This sort of thing can't just be summed up in a few lines - it requires full articles detailing test environments and results - you're better off searching the interweb for a blog or article with a full test and posting an answer to your own question here. It's a bit like asking "how many calories are in a sandwich with brown bread?". It depends on the ingredients!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Description...

**Windows 7 uses less CPU and Memory that Vista did. Windows 7 will run better on the same hardware than Vista.**

You may want to search for some of the reviews for a longer description with full details.

Also, as far as I can tell it requires about the same amount of disc space to install, but I'm not sure why you really care. It's not like the amount of disk space taken up by the bare installed OS really affects performance any.

Answer (score 1):

If it's able to run Vista, it'll run 7 better. If it's able to run XP reasonably well, it *could* run 7.

- [Windows Vista system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/get/system-requirements.aspx)
- [Windows 7 system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/system-requirements.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the answer to this is quite complex. For example, the Vista Kernel used to use 64K of memory to run in. In Windows 7 the Kernel team did a lot of work an the new Kernel only uses 32K of base memory. This seems like a minor change however it has a huge impact on the overall performance of the system and memory usage upwards. Apart from the user interface changes the whole core of the OS was optimized and this is the reason for the reduced requirements and better performance of Windows 7 overall.

There is numerous detailed articles on this all over the web. Specifically focus on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) and [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com) articles on this subject.